# What do I do when watching a video of someone praying?

Tags: prayer

Every once in a while I'll watch a message on video and the person in the video starts praying. Sometimes I feel compelled to pray along with them (especially if there's a group of us watching it), but then I feel silly as I realize I'm praying along with a *video*.

Is it nonsensical to pray along with what is essentially an audio clip? **I'm not talking about having my own individual prayer while the video is running. I'm talking about having a unified prayer of agreement along with the person/words that are coming out of the screen**.

Are there any examples in scripture of prayers being lifted up in such a way, obviously not with video but in some weird equivalent? Certainly God wants us to pray together and in groups and couples--what if it just so happens that the other "person" is a video? Is the spirit of unity and agreement still legit?

This is the kind of "agree" and "together" I'm talking about:

> **Matthew 18:19-20 ESV** Again I say to you, if two of you agree on earth about anything they ask, it will be done for them by my Father in heaven. For where two or three are gathered in my name, there am I among them.”

And the context of this verse was about 2 believers together, face-to-face, talking, and agreeing.

---

Edit: A good point was brought up: what if it's a live video stream? At that point the person is praying at the same time as you, but not together with you. Are you still praying *with* them even if they don't have a clue that you are? And (now this is messy) what if the video stream is an hour delayed?

Comment: How much difference would it make if it were a live video feed?

Comment: Is praying along with a recorded video/audio significantly any different from reading/reciting a pre-written prayer?

Comment: Prayer can time travel!

Comment: Are you basically asking if e-church is a legitimate replacement for actually going to church?

Answer (score 3):

I've wondered the same myself, especially during times when I'm watching a video of someone praying. However, technology allows people to communicate through Skype for instance. Which leads me to the belief that the spirit of unity and agreement is still legit. It may not be face to face, but it still matters, and there is still unity in that.

For example, Paul in his letters mentions praying for the different churches he is writing to all the time.

> “...God is my witness, whom I serve with my spirit in the gospel of
>   His Son, that without ceasing I make mention of you always in my
>   prayers” (Rom. 1:9, NKJV).

Even though it isn't in person, there is still unity in his prayer with the church in Rome. And there was quite a delay from Paul sending the letter to the recipients actually getting it.

So in my opinion, it doesn't matter if it's a live stream, delayed video, or whatever other thing you can think of. Prayer is conversing to God, and it doesn't matter if it's prerecorded or not.

Answer (score 0):

I always wonder this as well, when I watch sermons online. I believe that God sees our hearts, and He can see that we are willing to pray in agreement. So is it going to offend God or be unappreciated by Him? NO! I think that God is happy just to know that we have faith and we are making an effort to live out our faiths.

If you're the only person in the room praying along, it may cause some people to look at you funny, but what they think doesn't matter. They're not God.

I hope that this helps. God bless you.